# Create a character vector with repetition of elements

Tags: r, vector, character

I'm new to R and while practicing I couldn't work out how to create a vector whose outcome is :

> red yellow blue yellow blue green blue green magenta green magenta cyan .

I noticed that

> rep(seq(1:3),times=4) + rep(0:3, each=3)
>
> [1] 1 2 3 2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6

so I thought it cold be useful to create a vector such as

> colors <- c("red", "yellow", "blue","green","magenta","cyan")

and associate its values to the sequence but then I don't know how to go on.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: If the `rep` value is the index `colors[rep(seq(1:3),times=4) + rep(0:3, each=3)]`

Comment: @akrun great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use the index `vector` for expanding the 'colors'

```
colors[rep(seq(1:3),times=4) + rep(0:3, each=3)]
```